# Crunching Data in MongoDB. Aggregate or MR?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with this kind of data

```
{"uid":"uirerb68624gdbnxcc", "location": "AA", "hit": "foodcat", "aggdone": "n"} 
{"uid": "hdbhdhu7347fhdufh", "location": "BB", "hit": "travelcat", "aggdone": "n"}
{"uid": "uirerb68624gdbnxcc", "location": "CC", "hit": "travelcat", "aggdone": "n"}
```

So, you can see that there is one user who has more "hit"s than the other user. What do you suggest me to do to process these data above and push them in a different collection (i am free to do it once every week. I do not need it real time) like the following.

```
{"uid" : "uirerb68624gdbnxcc", "total_hits": 2}
{"uid" : "hdbhdhu7347fhdufh", "total_hits": 1}
```

Also, one thing very important, if you see the first collection, there is a key called "aggdone". which should act as a flag and should be marked "y" with all the data processed. So that next week when I start doing the same process I do not deal with all the data.

Please help me. Also, any suggestion/comments on the data design is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Mongo version 2.4.8

In response to the comment ------

I have a collection with documents like the following.

```
{
  "gpcId": "CGP_52400c5e301d5",
  "storageCreateTime": "1380270840",
  "autoUid": "1ea548e1-8970-4833-bc27-16871b0cba4a",
  "reportingTime": "1380271111",
  "userIP": "117.200.181.36"
}
```

So the autoUid can repeat many times for a particular gpcId with different reporting time. So that means we can (logically) get a list of top users (based on autoUid). This is exactly what i want to get and store in a different collection. So, ideally the resultant collection should look like

```
{ 
  "gpcId": "CGP_52400c5e301d5",
  "autoUid": "1ea548e1-8970-4833-bc27-16871b0cba4a"
  "total_count": 10
}
{ 
  "gpcId": "CGP_52400c5e301d5",
  "autoUid": "06a02b72-8470-4492-af5f-96ea0d1e8235"
  "total_count": 9
}
.
.
.
```

So, I would like to get some directions about how to achieve this. I have already mentioned my Mongo version. I am free to use PHP or Python at the back-end to do this.

I am sorry if I was not very clear first time.

Please tell me if something is still not clear.

Also, I have been trying to use map-reduce but i think that code is pointless to give here because i could not achieve any result which is even near to what I want.

Comment: Do you need help with a particular implementation? If so, you'll need to provide what you've tried so we can help. Otherwise, questions asking for code like this are generally marked to be held/closed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP did not try anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it out i think. This query bellow helped me. Please let me know if you think it can be made better.

db.mydb.aggregate({$match:{gpcId: "CGP_52400c5e301d5"}},{$group: {_id : "$autoUid", total_count: { $sum : 1 }}}, {$sort:{total_count: -1}})